# sql join tomfoolery (or How can I wind up with more rows than when I started?)

Tags: sql, ms-access

M$ Access 2010

table [CONTACT PERSON] has key field [Contact ID] and has 1599 rows.
table [Person Client Address Mailing] has key field [ClientID] and has 1465 rows.

Not all [CONTACT PERSON].[Contact ID] values have a
matching [Person Client Address Mailing].[ClientID]

So I'm buffaloed as to how this

```
SELECT aa.[Contact ID], bb.[cstreet1], bb.[cstreet2], bb.[cstreet3], bb.[ccity], bb.[cstate], bb.[czip], bb.[ccountry]
FROM [CONTACT PERSON] AS aa
LEFT JOIN [Person Client Address Mailing] AS bb
ON aa.[Contact ID] = bb.[ClientID]
ORDER BY aa.[Contact ID];
```

can return 1606 rows. My understanding is LEFT JOIN returns every row of the main table and all matching rows of the joined table . Therefore the number of rows returned will always be equal to the number of rows in the main table, never more. What gives? Or is this more Access-specific sql trickery?

[new data]

Turns out the above query is exactly right - the problem lies with duplicate rows in the joined table, which gets built with this query:

```
SELECT aa.[ClientID], aa.[cstreet1], aa.[cstreet2], aa.[cstreet3],
aa.[ccity], aa.[cstate], aa.[czip], aa.[ccountry]
FROM AAAddress_X AS aa
INNER JOIN (
            SELECT gg.[CLIENTID],
            MIN(gg.[sortOrderPersonPrimary]) AS sortOrderPersonPrimary
            FROM AAAddress_X AS gg
            WHERE gg.sortOrderPersonPrimary Is Not Null GROUP BY gg.[CLIENTID]) AS bb
ON aa.[CLIENTID] = bb.[CLIENTID] AND 
   aa.[sortOrderPersonPrimary] = bb.[sortOrderPersonPrimary]
WHERE aa.[cstreet1] <> ""
ORDER BY aa.[CLIENTID];
```

Running the inner query by itself yields 1458 rows, each ClientID-sortOrderPersonPrimary pairing is unique. And the sortOrderPersonPrimary value is in fact the minimum value, excellent. 1458 + 7 = 1465  so the duplicate rows must be coming in through the joining with the outer query. Which makes sense since there's 7 rows in AAAddress_X with matching ClientID-sortOrderPersonPrimary pairs.

So, follow-on question is, how can I adjust the above query to just return only the first occurance of each ClientID with the lowest sortOrderPersonPrimary value? Or maybe a different query, I'm not fussy.

Maybe I'm overcomplicating this, so I'll lay out what I have and what I need:

Example:
AAAddress contains some rows like this:
ClientID sortOrderPersonPrimary cstreet1 cstreet2.....
10107                         3 123 pine 
10108                         1 434 olson
10108                         1 5454 main
10108                         2 434 olivia
10109                         2 323 poplar

I need:
10107                         3 123 pine
10108                         1 434 olson
10109                         2 323 poplar

If there's no way to rid myself of these pesky duplicates in queries my Plan B is to manually pre-create an empty table [Person Client Address Mailing] with fields ClientID and sortOrderPersonPrimary both defined as keys, do an INSERT INTO SELECT... and let the keys implicitly weed out the dupes.

Thanks for everone's help so far! You guys rock!

Still-learning Steve

Answer (score 3):

You are right that only matches, which exists in both tables are returned. Could it be that you have duplicated entrys in your second table like:

```
Table 1

ID  NAME
1   foo

Table 2

ID      EMAIL
1     foo.bar@test.de
1     bar.ffo@test.de
```

then your LEFT JOIN will return 2 rows.

Comment: +1 Though, this may still be counter intuitive top the OP, as it requires Table2 to have more rows than Table1, which the OP does not have.  If we add two more people to your example, but don't give either of them an address, we get 3 rows in Table1, 2 rows in Table2, but 4 rows in the results.  Which is the specific case that the OP is dealing with.

Answer (score 0):

No, you just have duplicates in your IDs.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it returns all the values from the first table and matched records from the child table. However, your business logic  is that you may have more than one email for the same client; therefore when both tables are `Left joined` you will get duplicate records from the side of the MAIN TABLE. Also for the Clients who dont have any emails you will end up with `NULL` values on the right side of the query.

What you could do is use `INNER JOIN` and retrieve only the clients who have email addresses. Because `INNER JOIN` is sourcing only the matching values from both tables.

Last but not least, the main point is that even though you have:
table [CONTACT PERSON]- 1599 rows
table [Person Client Address Mailing] -1465 rows
It doesnt mean that you are going to end up with a defined list based on these figures, because you are dealing with Relational model and its all based on the relationships and data integrity.

Comment: example: client 1 has 3 emails and client 2 has 2emails;
therefore when the parent tbl(clients) is 'LEFT JOINED' to the child one, you will end up with 5 records in your dataset

Comment: Ah. Yes I have some duplicates in my second table: 7 ClientID's have 2 rows each. 1599 + 7 = 1606 so your analysis is correct. So I need to weed the duplicates out of this monster:

Comment: Why do you consider these as duplicates if they are different emails? Or in your case, do you have the exact same email record twice?

Comment: AAAddress_X has a key field AddressID but I can't match it to anything. Each row does in fact have a unique physical mailing address. There are many cases where multiple physical address map to the same ClientID ( main home/summer home etc...) sortOrderPersonPrimary is just one of many fields that help me sort the table different ways. And it works out that multiple rows can have the same ClientID-sortOrderPersonPrimary key-pair.